# How can I maintain multiple session in Jmeter for mobile application?

Tags: automation, jmeter

I want to use multiple user through CSV file so I am passing the login and password parameter and it's working file but I have multiple activity for each user so how can I maintain the session for the same?
Can I create multiple test case in single testplan?

Comment: why not? use controllers to separate test cases, or use different thread groups and pass session between thread groups

Answer (score 0):

Normally JMeter Thread represents a single user and [Thread Group](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) represents a group of users.

If groups of users (like authenticated users, guest users, admin users, users who perform search, users who just browse, etc.) have different anticipated amount of users or need to be isolated - just use different Thread Groups.

There is also a possibility to control requests execution frequency for different requests under a single Thread Group using [Throughput Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Throughput_Controller) or [Switch Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Switch_Controller). See [Running JMeter Samplers with Defined Percentage Probability](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/running-jmeter-samplers-defined-percentage-probability) article for detailed configuration.

With regars to "maintain the session" - it depends on how it is implemented in your application. For web applications it is mostly done via Cookies (and handled via [HTTP Cookie Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager)) or as a part of the URL (in that case [HTTP URL Re-writing Modifier](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_URL_Re-writing_Modifier) can be used), for mobile application I believe it would be either a request parameter containing user ID or some request header. Ask around or capture some same requests from different users using a sniffer tool like [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) and see what are the differences.